# Extjs: adding condition in listner for contextmenu

Tags: extjs

I have created the contextmenu, where when i click on grid it shown option on right click. As per my new requirement I want to add condition like when to show the right click option on grid. for some perticular condition I dont want to show that right click option.

My code:

```
listeners : {
        itemcontextmenu: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        e.stopEvent();   // Prevent the browser to show its default contextmenu
        this.contextMenu.index = index;   // It's important! you'll need the rowIndex (the row that right clicked on it) on future.
    this.contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());   // Get the current X and Y coordinates and show the gridCtxMenu (my custom created menu) on that location.
    var selectedUnitRecord = this.getStore().getAt(index);
    selectedUnitId = selectedUnitRecord.get('id');
        }
   }
```

My req is i want to add some thing like this logic:

```
if(type == 'dc'){
        /*Show option*/
    }else{
        /*dont Show option*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listeners : {
if(type == 'dc'){
return false;
}
        itemcontextmenu: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        e.stopEvent();   // Prevent the browser to show its default contextmenu
        this.contextMenu.index = index;   // It's important! you'll need the rowIndex (the row that right clicked on it) on future.
    this.contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());   // Get the current X and Y coordinates and show the gridCtxMenu (my custom created menu) on that location.
    var selectedUnitRecord = this.getStore().getAt(index);
    selectedUnitId = selectedUnitRecord.get('id');
        }
   }
```